Seeking tool to fix overlapping polygons in ArcGIS Pro
I'm looking for a GP tool that would fix the geometry of overlapping polygons in a feature class.
Basically it would check a ranking field in the attributes of each polygon and have the higher ranked polygons retain full geometry while the lower ranked polygon would have the geometry clipped by the higher ranked ones.
Basically it would do the same thing as the Erase tool but within one feature class and it would decide what to erase and what to keep based on a ranking field.
The end result should be a polygon feature class with no overlaps with higher ranked polygons always "winning out".
Is there anything like this available in Pro right off the bat or would I have to ArcPy my way out of this?

Have a look at the topology tools.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/an-overview-of-the-topology-toolset.htm

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. There are any number of such tools written. Unfortunately, they are likely written with respect to a specific use case which doesn't meet your definition of "fix". Topologies are very useful for identifying undershoot and overshoot issues, but I've never really been able to let them "fix" my problem without introducing new problems. I once had 8000 some-odd fixes to make, and was able to automate 6800 repairs, then the remainder required tedious review, with several hundred requiring manual edit.

You'll "have to ArcPy your way out of this" - assuming that you already searched for anyone having developed a tool that exactly matches your needs. It's non-trivial, but not an enormously complex task if there is no possibility of more than one overlapping polygons having the same rank.  Essentially, just split the layer by the rank field (see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm ), then iterate through the pairs of successive ranks and clip/erase each pair, then merge the results (and the top-ranking layer) back into a single feature class.

This can be done with advanced license. Picture shows polygon names and their dominance:


Use feature to polygon to get non-overlapping polygons (BITS), followed by feature to point (inside). Intersect points with 'parent' polygons. Sort this table in descending order by 'valence' and delete duplicates by ORIG_FID. What remains:

Can be joined to BITS using ORIG_FID, and BITS dissolved by polygon name:

